# Difference of meaning in sentences below

Tags: meaning

Are there any meaning difference in sentences below? I used a phrase both before adjective and after adjective . If there is any difference Can you please explain why?

> Constructor built a one feet taller wall than constructional project required.
>
> Constructor built a wall one feet taller than constructional project required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One minor correction - as it is only *one* foot, don't use the plural "feet". It doesn't matter how many feet tall it is in its entirety - you're talking about the differential of one foot.

Both sentences are correct, both ultimately mean the same thing.

- The first one makes the additional height an attribute of the wall. The wall *is* a one-foot taller wall than was required.
- The second attributes the additional height to the building work. The constructor *built it* one foot taller than was required.

Comment: Agreed, though I'd possibly suggest the construction project has the additional height attribute, rather than the actual building work.  Also, as @jeff-morrow says, I'd add a suggestion to change 'constructional' to 'construction' in 'constructional project required'.

Comment: I think the first one would be much easier to follow if it was properly hyphenated: _a one-foot-taller wall_.  (One of my bugbears is that both US and UK Englishes don't hyphenate enough, though for opposite reasons.)

Answer (score 5):

Neither is idiomatic in American English though both will be understood to mean the same thing.

"Constructor" is not a familiar word in American English: either "builder" or "contractor" are far more likely, depending on context.

"One foot" rather than "one feet."

The adjectival phrase would normally follow the noun in this kind of comparative.

"Constructional" is not a familiar word: "construction" would be used. However, it is not needed.

> The builder built the wall one foot higher than the construction project required

is idiomatic but likely would shortened to

> The wall was built one foot higher than required.